# Typescript deep replace multiple types

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, conditional-types

I use mongodb with @types/mongodb. This gives me a nice FilterQuery interface for my mogodb queries for a collection of  shaped documents. In my domain object class  I have some extra logic like converting dates to moment objects or floats to BigNumber objects.

For my queries I need to convert these back, so for example a Moment object needs to be converted to a date object and so on. To avoid duplication and maintaining a separate interface (just for the queries) I thought of using mapped types to replace all types of Moment to type of Date

```
type DeepReplace<T, Conditon, Replacement> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Conditon
    ? Replacement
    : T[P] extends object
    ? DeepReplace<T[P], Conditon, Replacement>
    : T[P];
};


class MyDoaminClass {
  date: Moment;
  nested: {
    date: Moment;
  };
}

const query: DeepReplace<MyDoaminClass, Moment, Date> = {
  date: moment().toDate(),
  nested: {
    date: moment().toDate()
  }
};
```

This basically works, but I have about 4-5 of these types that I would need to replace. Is there an elegant way to chain several DeepReplace Types or even better: Specify all type replacements in one place? I would like to avoid something like `type ReplaceHell = DeepReplace<DeepReplace<DeepReplace<MyDoaminClass, Moment, Date>, BigNumber, number>, Something, string>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to do the replacement "all at once" and *not* as a "chain" (meaning that you don't intend to, say, replace `X` with `Y` and *then* replace `Y` with `Z`), then you can rewrite `DeepReplace` to take a union `M` of mapping tuples corresponding to `[Condition1, Replacement1] | [Condition2, Replacement2] | ...`.  So your old `DeepReplace<T, C, R>` would be `DeepReplace<T, [C, R]>`.  The definition would look like this:

```
type DeepReplace<T, M extends [any, any]> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends M[0]
    ? Replacement<M, T[P]>
    : T[P] extends object
    ? DeepReplace<T[P], M>
    : T[P];
}
```

where `Replacement<M, T>` finds the mapping tuple in `M` where `T` is assignable to the condition and returns the corresponding replacement, and is defined like this:

```
type Replacement<M extends [any, any], T> =
    M extends any ? [T] extends [M[0]] ? M[1] : never : never;
```

Let's see if it works on some types I'll make up here. Given the following:

```
interface DateLike {
    v: Date;
}
interface StringLike {
    v: string;
}
interface NumberLike {
    v: number;
}

interface Original {
    a: {
        dat: DateLike;
        str: StringLike;
        num: NumberLike;
        boo: boolean
    },
    b: {
        arr: NumberLike[]
    },
    c: StringLike,
    d: number
}
```

Let's replace the `...Like` types:

```
type Replaced = DeepReplace<Original, 
  [DateLike, Date] | [StringLike, string] | [NumberLike, number]
>

/* equivalent to
type Replaced = {
    a: {
        dat: Date;
        str: string;
        num: number;
        boo: boolean;
    };
    b: {
        arr: number[];
    };
    c: string;
    d: number;
}
*/
```

So that works.

---

Please note that calling the new `DeepReplace<T, [C, R]>` this probably has the same edge cases the original `DeepReplace<T, C, R>` has.  For example, unions like `{a: string | DateLike}` won't be mapped.  I'll consider any tweaking of these to be outside the scope of the question.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-yiAD0ACpSABHdGyNYMjxQYCqCrgEMxiDhgTslmmx22LnAHmUFUCoV6IUIs0SWW+xWkyeSbVajW6ljzp1Hk1M1VDS0bkn2o8lI+u4tikFHn27P1bz6N+tiIA)

Comment: Epicly eye-opening! I spent 8 hours writing my own version of the same mapped type. Stuck at the same tuple/union array as you mentioned. I was gonna open a new question for that and then found your elegant answer. Your code is half the size of my own version. Do you know if it's possible to handle the union issue? If you want, I can still open a new question. I have added some tests here https://gist.github.com/ivawzh/af3d3bcd9f9f1bfa82f49c523d6c3672#file-deep-replace-ts-L6

Comment: If after `[P in keyof T]:` you wrap everything in `T[P] extends infer TP ? ... : never` and replace any `T[P]` inside the `...` with `TP`, it should distribute the replacement over unions.  If you want more information you should probably open a new question, since I don't think comments are good places for too much new code.

Comment: thanks, I have just created a new question with some more spec https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274898/typescript-mapped-type-that-deep-transforms-with-tuple-union-support